# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in netty-socketio server

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to start `netty-socketio` server, and I can't trace origins of this exception. I have marked in stacktrace place where it may lead to the answer, so if anyone could provide explanation on this it will be much appreciated.

```
public class SocketIoServer {
    private Configuration cnf = new Configuration();
    private SocketIOServer server;

    public SocketIoServer() {

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(8081);

        server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

When I initialize socket an Exception gets thrown. Here's context:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:112)
    at com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer.<init>(SocketIOServer.java:66)
    at SocketIoServer.<init>(SocketIoServer.java:17)
    at Server.main(Server.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:109)
    ... 8 more
```

**This line in particular**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule.setSerializerModifier(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule;
    at com.corundumstudio.socketio.protocol.JacksonJsonSupport.init(JacksonJsonSupport.java:316)
    at com.corundumstudio.socketio.protocol.JacksonJsonSupport.<init>(JacksonJsonSupport.java:311)
    at com.corundumstudio.socketio.protocol.JacksonJsonSupport.<init>(JacksonJsonSupport.java:304)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have obviously a conflict of version of [`jackson-databind`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) in your project, indeed the class `com.corundumstudio.socketio.protocol.JacksonJsonSupport` relies on the method [`SimpleModule#setSerializerModifier(BeanSerializerModifier mod)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html#setSerializerModifier(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier)) which has been added since the version `2.2` so as it cannot find this method, it means that you have a version of `jackson-databind` older than `2.2` in your classpath such that the method cannot be found.

Check all the jars that you have in your classpath and make sure that you have only one version of `jackson-databind` corresponding to the version expected by `netty-socketio`. For example assuming that you use the version `1.7.12` of `netty-socketio`, the expected version of `jackson-databind` is `2.7.4` as you can see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.corundumstudio.socketio/netty-socketio/1.7.12).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.